# Bootstrap-select misplacing list when using data-container

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I have a html select using Bootstrap-select library. If I define no `data-container` the list works OK but I have a problem of overlapping. Basically, I am rendering the select (without `data-container`) inside a container which must have `overflow-y: auto;`. When the select tries to open above a navbar (main menu) it is overlapped and cut. See [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/f7f7fpab/2/) (you must force the dropdown to be opened as drop UP).

The proper solution for me, I think it would be to define a `data-container`. However, as soon as I do this, the list is misplaced. See [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/f7f7fpab/) (you must force the dropdown to be opened down, not up).

Another suggested workaround was to set `data-container="body"` instead of my own container div as previous example. This DID solve the first scenario, but it breaks for other cases. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7f7fpab/4/) and dropdown the list "State" (so that it is opened below) and you will see how the list is misplaced (but below where it should be) letting a big empty space between the dropdown button.

Note that I would appreciate the same solution to be applied everywhere, not a solution that I would need to adjust for every place I render a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the master branch of bootstrap-select, and will be available officially in v1.11.0. See https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/commit/f2358a15e7b3cdba519a22ada9b7654ab6775255.

Answer (score 0):

*Continuing discussion from : https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1422*

What do you mean by "a problem of overlapping" ? The fact that the select options are displayed over the heading is not an UX issue for me : this is how the native select works, and users can still click elsewhere to dismiss the menu.

Specifying a data-container would just limit the options menu inside that container, which might not be optimal for your case. Additionally, the issue specified above states that there is a positionning issue with this option.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question with more information. Please let me know what do you think. Thanks!

Comment: This seems indeed related to the above issue. However, unlike my issue, you don't have a `position:absolute` for your container.

This means you could just use `data-container="body"` and this should work fine.

See this updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f7f7fpab/3/

Comment: Thanks @cube45 I have added yet another JSFiddle in the updated question and as you can see, the `data-container="body"` does fix that but breaks other cases :(

Answer (score 0):

just add the position: sticky; in bootstrap-select.css to the below class

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: sticky;
}
```